# Does a completely metrizable space admit a compatible metric where all intersections of nested closed balls are non-empty?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

It is well-known that given a metric space $(X,d)$, the metric is complete if and only if every intersection of nested (i.e. decreasing with respect to inclusion) closed balls of vanishing diameters have non-empty intersection. This is usually referred to as Cantor's Intersection Theorem.

My question basically is:

*Is it true that every completely **metrizable** topological space **admits one compatible metric** such that every intersection of nested closed balls has a non-empty intersection?*

---

I will give some more details:

Let's call spherically complete a metric as above where every intersection of nested closed balls has non-empty intersection.

I'm very aware that not every complete metric is spherically complete. Only on this forum, there are several discussions on similar topics (see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314912/in-a-metric-space-the-intersection-of-nested-closed-balls-is-empty) and the list of its related questions).

However, my question is not about a fixed metric, but about the existence of one single compatible metric for a topological space.
And a priori, it seems possible to me that even a metric space whose metric is not spherically complete may still admit another compatible spherically complete metric.

We know that there exist spaces that have spherically complete metrics.

For example:

- All (complete) metrics on a compact space are spherically complete.
- The standard euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is spherically complete.
- All completely ultrametrizable spaces admit a compatible spherically complete metric.

I suspect that every locally compact completely metrizable space admits a spherically complete metric, and probably the same is true for Polish spaces (using that they are homeomorphic to $G_\delta$ subsets of the Hilbert cube).
But I could not find any reference for this.

So to be more precise my question is:

- Do all completely metrizable topological spaces admit a compatible spherically complete metric?
- If not, is it known what is the largest class of (completely metrizable) topological spaces that admit one?

Even an answer/reference only for locally compact or Polish spaces would be nice. Thank you!

*Edit (April 24th): If in a few more days there won't be an answer, I'll try cross-posting this on MathOverflow as well.*

Comment: The counterexample [in this link you provided](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987357/cantors-intersection-theorem-without-the-diameter-hypothesis) is a complete metric space and a nested family of closed ***subsets*** which have empty intersection. But those subsets are not closed balls, and therefore that nested sequence of closed subsets does ***not*** disprove sphericallly complete. I think perhaps you are not being careful enough about the difference between a closed ball and a closed subset?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant to give a couple of links to show that this forum has many questions on similar topics. But as I wrote it is misleading. I will change this now. 

But while it is true the closed sets provided in the link you mentioned (as you rightly pointed out) are not closed balls *in the usual Euclidean metric*, I guess it shouldn't be hard to find other complete metrics in which they are closed balls, which would be enough for our purpose?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446378/does-a-completely-metrizable-space-admit-a-compatible-metric-where-all-intersect)

Comment: See the answer to this problem here: (https://mathoverflow.net/a/446702/61536)